# Linux commands to add an Active Directory group in Sudoers file

Tags: linux, sudo, active-directory

What is the Linux (Red Hat) command to add a Active Directory (AD) group in `sudoers` file to restrict the local admin access to the members of the group?

For eg, I have an AD group `linux-admin` and I would like to add this line

```
%test.com\linux-admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note:  Messing with the `sudoers` file has some risk. Before starting, things to think about include:

- System backups
- A physical root shell (in a properly configured ssh environment root should be dis-sallowed from logging into a system over ssh)
- Familiarity with booting off a live cd to "fix" whatever is broken

Assuming you have AD integration already in place,

> groups

will list all the groups that a user has, this is important so that you get the proper casing for the group name.

take that and then add it to `/etc/sudoers` file.  I use `nano` and add one of these lines at the bottom of the file.

> %domain\groupname   ALL=(ALL) ALL

or

> %groupname   ALL=(ALL) ALL

A domain may or may not be needed. That is a function of other decisions in setting up the AD authentication integration.  If AD authenticated users are dumped into `/home/<DOMAIN>/<username>`, then you'll most likely need the exact same name as DOMAIN in the `sudoers` file.

To automate this from a script, call

> echo "%groupname      ALL=(ALL)ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

Comment: That's great. But how do I add this line to the file without opening the file. The reason I am trying to do this is to automate this.

Comment: I added a automation note.  Backup sudoers before you do this, and re-verify after to make sure it's right.

Comment: Not only take a backup, but make sure you have a root shell open somewhere too

Comment: I wasn't looking beyond the question, but you're right.  If considerations aren't included, someone will do this without proper preparation.  I added a note at the top to clarify things.